# Is there a way to search for posts with an associated fiddle?

Tags: support, search

I'm curious if there is a way to search for questions / answers that consist of **only** a [fiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFiddle)? Perhaps we can search for [JSFiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFiddle) / [RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/) in the answers.

Ideally I want to see only answers that are accepted *and* have fiddles.

Comment: You could probably do such a search on data.se, if you put your mind do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the advanced search options for this.  Search for:

> url:"jsfiddle.net*" is:answer isaccepted:yes

The above search yeilds [over 79,000 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url:%22jsfiddle.net*%22%20is:answer%20isaccepted:yes).

Comment: thx, this is a stretch but do you know if there is any way to do the url call in only accepted answers (yeah, I know).

Comment: @timpone, `isaccepted:yes`, as Bill says in his answer?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi cool, are those modifiers to the question (a question/answer that has url jsfiddle.net and is answered and an an answer is accapted) or to the url query (the existence of url jsfiddle.net in an answer and that answer is accepted)

Comment: @timpone, if my understanding of the new search system is correct, search terms are implicitly connected with `AND`, so by saying `is:answer` you're basically rejecting all questions. The end result will only consist in accepted answers containing a link to jsFiddle.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's the way I understand it. The `url:` piece searches all posts, `is:answer` narrows it down to answers only, then `isaccepted:yes` narrows it down further.

Comment: cool thx, my first time using these so really appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Google search with the jsfiddle link and the SITE: option.

Example: Googling for

> ["jsfiddle.net/hvqz7/ site:stackoverflow.com"](http://www.google.com/#q=jsfiddle.net%2Fhvqz7%2F+site:stackoverflow.com)

yields

[what's wrong with my fiddle using jqueryui selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416080/whats-wrong-with-my-fiddle-using-jqueryui-selectable)

---

If you're looking for fiddle-only answers to cast moderator flags against, try this: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=fiddle

Comment: I think he's trying to do something like search for bad questions/answers that are link-only.

Comment: Oh.  I misread the question then.

Comment: It's just a guess.